# Is the maximum likelihood estimator for the mean equal to the sample mean under all densities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Suppose, I have a sample from an unknown distribution. I want to prove/disprove (mathematically!) the following statement:

*The maximum likelihood (ML) estimator for the (unknown) population mean will always be equal to the sample mean irrespective of the likelihood function. We suppose that, the likelihood function is twice differentiable with respect to its parameters and the mean and variance is finite under the inverse likelihood function (pdf).*

I believe for symmetric distributions it is straightforward. To maximize the likelihood the center of the mass should be placed at the mean. So, sample mean should be the best estimator to maximize the likelihood of the observed data. But I can not relate to it mathematically.

Comment: The issue is you need to first define what a MLE is. If it is simply an estimator which maximizes the likelihood, then the issue is that the likelihood need not be a function of the mean, but some other parameters.

Comment: @Andrew Those other parameters will definitely map to mean in the end. For me, ML estimation is always about where to locate the center of the mass of the proposed pdf and how to scale it. 
I do not see vagueness in the question. Suppose you have Exponential distribution and the MLE estimator of the $\theta$ is equal to the inverse of the sample mean. It does not mean that we can not get the ML estimator for the mean! Finally, I assumed that the mean and variance is finite under the proposed pdf.

Comment: Take a look at the lognormal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.  The maximum likelihood estimate of the distribution mean is $e^{\hat{\mu}+\hat{\sigma}^2}$ which is not generally equal to the sample mean.  Or  try a single parameter distribution such as a chisquare with 1 degree of freedom.

Comment: @JimB Good intuition. Thank you.  Can we prove the statement for the natural exponential family with quadratic variance function? I guess, the picture gets clearer now. If the variance of the distribution is a quadratic function of the mean then, the MLE estimator will always be equal to the mean, because the mean is the minimized of the quadratic loss. If for example, variance is the absolute value of the deviations then median will be the MLE estimator. But that does not make the statement valid because we assumed differentiability.

Comment: BTW: if that were true, then the ML would coincide with the method of moments (at least for the estimation of the mean).

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a little underspecified; you need to specify a parametric family of distributions, it's not enough to just say "an unknown distribution," or else it's not clear what "maximum likelihood estimate" means.

Anyway, this is false in general. Consider, for example, the uniform distribution on $[0, \theta]$ where $\theta$ is the unknown parameter to be estimated (so $\frac{\theta}{2}$ is the true mean). It's an easy exercise to show that the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ from $n$ samples $X_1, \dots X_n$ is $\text{max}(X_1, \dots X_n)$, meaning the MLE of the true mean is half this.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the statement. But I guess the refined statement will hold for all NEF  with quadratic variance function as I mentioned in my reply above to Jim.

Comment: +1. But wouldn't transformation invariance of likelihood imply that the MLE of the mean is $\frac{\theta}{2}$ -- still, your point stands that $\max(X_1,...,X_n)/2 \neq \bar{X}$

Comment: I get how this is a counter example of OP's statement. On a tangent, how would you explain the inconsistency of the uniform distribution with the Law of Large Numbers, which states that the sample mean will converge to the population mean as the sample converges to infinity?

Comment: @Amazonian: there's no inconsistency with the law of large numbers here. The sample mean does converge to the true mean, it's just that the sample mean is not the maximum likelihood estimator of the true mean.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how do you show that the sample mean of an iid sample from the uniform distribution converges to the true mean?

Comment: You can appeal to the law of large numbers or do a (possibly somewhat tedious) direct calculation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution